# On smooth monotone functions with uncountably many inflection points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am running a problems class in Analysis and our discussion lead to the question as to whether $C^1$ strictly monotone functions can admit an infinite number of stationary points. By Sard's theorem, the set of stationary points must have Lebesgue measure zero, and since any such function would necessarily be injective it's clear that these stationary points must be inflection points. I was able to construct a smooth, strictly increasing function with a countable number of inflection points as follows. We use a standard "transition function" - so let

$$ \begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if } x \geq 0 \newline 0  & x > 0 
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}$$

and then take

$$ \begin{equation}
g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)} & \text{if } x \in [0,1] \newline 0 & \text{ else} 
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}$$

So g strictly increases from $0$ to $1$ on $[0,1]$ with no stationary points. So scaling these and gluing them together we get a function

$$h(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k} g(2^{k}x + 2) $$

This function is continuous, strictly increasing, has a countable number of inflection points and is smooth at every point except $x=1$ where I believe the derivative is discontinuous. See an image from Desmos below.

[image]

So I have the following questions - this function is $C^1$, in fact smooth, away from a single point. Would it be possible to construct a function on the closed interval and not just an open interval? Furthermore, could such a function be constructed with an uncountably infinite number of inflection points? My intuition says no, but for an example I was imagining a Cantor staircase construction with a transition function between each step but I'm unsure if this would work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sard's theorem only guarantees that the the image of the critical points has measure zero; you can have functions where $\{x:f'(x)=0\}$ has full measure, like a constant function. To exclude these sorts of examples, you presumably want your function to be strictly monotone?

Comment: Ah yes my mistake! Good point. Yes I was considering in particular strictly monotone functions, this question arose when we were talking about injective functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking at Sard's theorem I had come up with the following construction, which indeed follows your idea.

You simply consider $K$  the typical Cantor set on $[0,1]$ and consider $f(x)=d(x,K)$. Where $d$ is the distance. Notice since $K$ is closed that $f$ is zero precisely over $K$. It is also continuous, so all that is left is to integrate $f$, yielding an increasing $C^1$ function with stationary points $K$.
For a smooth function, there is a famous result, (for instance in Walter Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis exercise 5.21) that every closed set is the zeros of a smooth positive function.
Again integrating such a function defined by the Cantor set yields the desired result I hope.

Comment: Brilliant! That's an excellent solution, I hadn't thought of trying to work backwards from the derivative. That Rudin exercise is also very interesting, should be applicable in many more cases.